# Extract from DataBase using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2005, extract

I wrote a small script in Python that could help me to extract data from a database. Here is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

#connect to server
mytab = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://test:test1@mypass')

#sql query that retrieves my table
df = pd.read_sql('select * from FO_INV', mytab)

#query result to excel file 
df.to_csv('inventory.csv', index=False, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Everything works fine if I choose to select top 100 rows for example. But for the whole table, it take forever !!! 
Do you have any idea or recommendations, please ? 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I guess the slowness is due to `sqlalchemy`. Try using `pyodbc` and check the time.

Comment: The obvious questions are how many rows in the tables, how much data per row, and what are the memory characteristics of the computer that's running the process?

Comment: About 1,000,000 rows and I am running it on a virtual desktop... Not to heavy datas, just int and strings !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `pyodbc` instead of `SQLALCHEMY`.

Something like this:

```
import pyodbc
mytab = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=.\;DATABASE=myDB;UID=user;PWD=pwd')
```

Check your timings with this. This should be faster.